# What's the right way to kill NPAPI plugin instance when close browser's page-tab but not quit the browser process?

Tags: process, exit, npapi

On Windows, when close the referenced browser's tab, the plugin process will quit immediately. But on mac os x, when I close the browser's tab (not quit the browser's process), the plugin process still keep a long time, after that, it closed abnormal.
Then my question is that how can I quit the NPAPI plugin process normally? Thanks for your answer and sorry for my poor English.
BTW, my OS is mac os x 10.8, and I use Xcode 4.5.

Because my plugin must support chrome, I used 32-bit arch and I cannot use OC's ARC, and then I must manage memory manually. When I check my code, I doubt in the each time call NPP_GetValue I should use browser->retainObject, but only call releaseObject once when the instance is destroyed. I do not sure it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. It's not up to you when the plugin process should end, it's up to the browser. Chrome, for instance, keeps plugin processes alive for a short time to avoid thrashing if someone, say, reloads a page with the only instance of the plugin, or navigates between two pages with the same plugin.

Your bug isn't that the process is staying alive for a while, it's that it's crashing when it does exit. You should debug and fix your crash.

Comment: What do you mean copy of the plugin? I mean that if I open many browser tabs with the same URL, the plugin should gen the same number of instances as the number of caller. Perhaps my question should be "How can I kill the plugin instance in right way?" not kill the plugin process, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: That far too broad a question. The correct way to handle the destruction of a plugin instance (which I assume is what you mean by "kill a plugin"; the browser starts the destruction of an instance, not you) is to clean up your code correctly. How you do that depends on your code. You are essentially asking people to debug a crash that you've given no information about in code that they can't see. You need to post a new question with specific details about the crash, and the related code, if you want someone to help.

Comment: In fact what i want to do is play video from web stream. As the apple's core animation movie plugin example, when i load a local movie in the plugin and play it, after I close the browser tab, the example plugin process's also did not close in time.

Comment: BTW, can you tell me how can I open a debug window to show logs when i'm debug my plugin? As it is a bundle, i open the web page which will load my plugin, and i attach xcode to the plugin process, but the NSLog info did not show on the console. If i want to see the debug info, what's the good way? Thanks.

Comment: What i want to do is show the NSLog information, i have attach the plugin process and use breakpoint to debug the plugin, but it's not very convenient. I use NSLog but the string did not show on the console when i attaching to the plugin process and debugging it.

Comment: If you want to ask a totally new question about how to get stdout when debugging a plugin process, post a new question. The comment system is not intended for that.